# Python - Multiple HTTP requests too slow

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to Python programming.

I am trying to parse the HTTP requests from Instagram to find a specific word using regular expressions.

I've used multiprocessing, but still it's SLOW. I know my code might look stupid, but that's my best.

What am I doing wrong that makes it slow? I need to make it send multiple HTTP requests faster.

```
import requests
import re 
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


Nthreads = cpu_count()*2
pool = Pool(Nthreads)


f = open('full.txt','r')
fw = open('out.txt', 'w')


def findSnap(bio):
    regex = 'content=".*sn[a]*p[a-z]*\s*[^a-z0-9].*'
    snap = re.findall(regex, bio)
    if not snap:
        return None
    else:
        afterSnap = re.sub('content=".*sn[a]*p[a-z]*\s*[^a-z0-9]*\s*','',snap[0])
        if afterSnap:
            afterSnap = re.findall('[\w_\.-]*',afterSnap)[0]
            sftS = afterSnap.split()
            if sftS:
                return sftS[0]
            return None
        return None

def loadInfo(url):
    #print 'Loading data..'
    st = time.time
    try:
        page = requests.get(url).text.lower()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Something is wrong!')
        return None


    snap = findSnap(page)
    if snap:
        fw.write(snap + '\n')
        fw.flush()
        print(snap)
    else:
        return None
    return snap

start = time.time()
names = f.read().splitlines()
baseUrl = 'https://instagram.com/'
urls = map(lambda x: baseUrl + x, names)

pool.map(loadInfo, urls)
finish = time.time()

print((finish- start)/60)
fw.close()
```

Comment: What's the time result then ?

Comment: "But still it's SLOW". Compared to what? Perhaps the servers you're making requests to are slow, or your internet connection? Then you could speed up the script all you want, but it won't help you. Please try to figure out first what part is slow.

Comment: Why would have a number of threads twice the amount of your CPU cores, by the way?

Comment: What @Evert said, but also, please tell how fast you expect the program to be, how fast it actually is, and also how large your dataset is (i.e. the number of lines in `full.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

As some people is saying, maybe we need some more details about what times are you getting, what are you expecting and why you expect that. Because there are a lot factors that can be involved in the execution time of your application, not just your code, because your application depends on a third-party resource.

In any case, I have seen you are using `multiprocessing.dummy`, this is just a wrapper of `threading` module [[1](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)]. Following its documentation, it seems it is not the best module you can use to run regular Python code at same time[[2](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-objects)]:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global
>   Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once
>   (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome
>   this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of
>   the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to
>   use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.
>   However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run
>   multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

It is true that in your case you are making I/O operations, but processing regex is also a heavy task.

As it is said in the text, you can try to use different implementations of pools 
 in `multiprocessing` module other than `dummy` or you can `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` also.